# React Jest Enzyme testing function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm still learning about react testing. Can you show me how to test this? I have it like this but didn't work. I have added the reducer below.

```
export const getUserData = (data) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const user = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/users/${data}`).then(res => res.json())
    await dispatch(getUser(user))
    return user
}


import { getUserData } from "../userReducers";

global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
        json: () => ({ login: 'Someone' })
    })
)

describe("Testing user reducers", () => {
    it("will hit mock API and get response", () => {
        const response = getUserData('Someone')
        expect(response).toEqual({ login: 'Someone' })
    })
})

export const GET_USER = "GET_USER";

export const getUser = (user) => ({
    type: GET_USER,
    payload: user,
});
```

Comment: Are you wanting to test a reducer, or just that action creator specifically?

Comment: I want to test a reducers @DrewReese

Comment: Can you update your question to include the reducer function you want to exercise?

Comment: I have added a dispatch function there. @DrewReese

Comment: A reducer function has a function signature like `(state, action) => nextState`. To test you call the reducer function and pass it some test state and the result of invoking an action creator. Assert the "nextState" is the value you expect.

Comment: Well, when you add the reducer code you want to test to your question feel free to (at) me in a comment.

Comment: Hi Reese, I have solved it using the solving by Viet (below). But I have another problem now. Do you know how to mock the getUserData function? because when I use that global.fetch, it returns me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236274/discussion-between-lelianto-pradana-and-drew-reese).

Comment: That is interesting, considering it doesn't call a reducer function at all. I guess you successfully tested an action function. 

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async/await` like this:

```
it("will hit mock API and get response", async () => {
    const dispatch = mock.fn();
    const getState = mock.fn();
    const response = await getUserData('Someone')(dispatch,  getState);
    expect(response).toEqual({ login: 'Someone' })
    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Comment: by the way, how if I have a dispatch inside the reducer,

export const getUserData = (data) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
 const user = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/users/${data}`).then(res => res.json())
 await dispatch(getUser(user))
 return user
}

Comment: TypeError: dispatch is not a function. I got this when I try to add dispatch.

Comment: You can mock `dispatch` and test it have been called

Comment: do you have any reference to make a dispatch mock?

Comment: I will try it first, but let me asking you again if there is any problem.

Comment: Hi, By the way, I can make the dispatch mock and already get the return. the return is unpredictable everytime, so I have to make global.fetch

`global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
 Promise.resolve({
  json: () => ({ login: 'Someone' })
 })
)`

Have you any idea to mock the function?

Comment: I got this TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined